# is there an api out there for mountains?

Tags: google-maps

I'd love to find a rest api containing info related to mountains, specifically elevation and coordinates. While I realize this question is not directly related to google maps, I am curious to know if anyone has done this with any of googles apis or the likes. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Digital Elevation Model" is the term to look for.  e.g. http://ned.usgs.gov/

It's not an API, it's a dataset and you'll need to import it, store it and build your own API on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Vay Studio provides a free (up to 10,000 requests per month) [Rest API For Mountains](https://vay.studio/explore/mountain-search/).

They source their data from the USGS, and currently they only support the United States.

Disclaimer: I made this API.

Comment: Seemingly not anymore.